# Use the same port (443) for hosting multiple applications

Tags: windows, openvpn, https, tcp

I have a Windows Server. I am hosting multiple websites on port 443 using the Host Header Binding in IIS. This works great, however, I am looking for a solution to somehow be able to use port 443 to run an OpenVPN server on the same windows machine.

Is there some way I can use IIS to bind a vpn.example.com port to 443 and make it route all incoming connections to an internal port, e.g 8080, which will host the OpenVPN application, or does anyone know of a possible application/workaround that will accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible.

Making OpenVPN use port `443` is possible and an useful way of bypassing a firewall that has port `443` open. That's because both HTTPS and OpenVPN uses TLS encryption, making it almost* impossible to distinguish one from another.

However, while **OpenVPN** utilizes the common TLS encryption, it **doesn't implement HTTP** protocol; the one having the `Host:` header allowing the *name based virtual hosts*. Therefore, you'll need another IP address for your OpenVPN server.

(*) Some *deep packet inspection* may have ability to detect patterns that doesn't match HTTPS.

Comment: What about port multiplexers?